# NGinx not able to redirect to /admin or any other page even when they are defined in location block

Tags: nginx

So I created this Nginx config file and everytime I'm trying to open page with URL/admin or URL/swagger I'm still getting redirected to /URL/home which is pretty weird. I have tried a lot of things already but nothing worked. It would be great help if someone can review my config and point what I'm missing here.

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.abc.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.abc.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    root /home/ubuntu/abc-frontend/dist;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name app.abc.com;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        location ~*\.(?:ico|css|js|json|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                expires 15d;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        }
    }

    location /api/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/abc;
        proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/abc.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location /admin/?(.*) {
        alias /home/ubuntu/abc;
        proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/abc.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location /maintenance_admin/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/abc;
        #proxy_pass http://abc;
        proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/abc.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location /swagger/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/abc;
        #proxy_pass http://abc;
        proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/abc.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    app.abc.com;
    return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Comment: Firstly, `location /admin/?(.*)` will not work as you expect. You have written a regular expression, but omitted the regular expression operator. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with your location blocks:
Try to substitute with the following:

With the = this block will be considered a match if the request URi exactly matches de location given.

```
location = / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    location ~*\.(?:ico|css|js|json|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
            expires 15d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
    }
}
```

I think that will solve your problem, anyways if it doesn't you can try to add ~ at the beggining of the blocks like this:

```
location ~ api/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/abc;
    proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/abc.sock;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

Also you can check this post for a better understanding
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: I happen to do some more research on this and although this didn't help I found the problem is with how the caching is being configured. Can you help me with the caching parameters and why always the cached home page is thrown to users.